# Django + encoding

Tags: django

I'm having problems with character encoding it.
I tried to convert as follows:

```
def TranslateMe(string,toLan):

    try:
        string = smart_str(string)
    except:
        string = smart_unicode(string)  

    ident = hashlib.md5(string).hexdigest()
    translated,created = myString.objects.get_or_create(ident=ident,languageTo=toLan)
    translated.original = string
    translated.save()

    if translated.translated:
        return translated.translated
    else:
        return string

register.filter(TranslateMe)
```

The problem is when I use accented characters, such as `ã é ç â`. Can someone help me?

The page os snippet: https://github.com/olarva/Django-template-Tag-Translator

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is already done using gettext in Django core. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/ for a complete rundown.